# How can I implement a syntax highlighting schemes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Say I want to implement syntax highlighting in an application. The medium is not a Windows Form, therefore I won't be highlighting text in a normal textbox. Instead I just want to be able to read and understand the same information that Visual Studio uses to highlight text, and apply the logic where I need it. In case it is somehow relevant the target medium is an XNA window.

Is this legal and/or possible? If so, where do I find such an API?

EDIT: If anyone is curious, I am embedding an IronPython interpreter in an XNA window. It would be nice to be able to treat input and output to the same syntax highlighting that IronPython receives in Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't think the logic Visual Studio uses is available, but there are many many code colorizer components available from third-parties, both paid and free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend checking out [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) with some additional info [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).

**Update**:  Given your updated information (in the comments below) I would recommend [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) which is a Python syntax highlighting engine.

Comment: Markdown has requirements I can't handle but I'll go looking for more third party tools now, thanks.

Comment: Just curious.  What are your limiting requirements?  Note: [SO] uses markdown-based syntax highlighting.  :O)

Comment: It looks like Markdown requires perl (?) and this is an XNA game meant to run on Windows. I could install perl I guess, and distribute it with the finished product, but I don't know anything about it and considering my edited post which explains why I asked the original question, seems a little convoluted (don't you think?).

Comment: Certainly.  I would not go the Perl route for an XNA game.  But then I must ask, where were you looking to visualize source code *within* the game?  And further, if it isn't dynamically generated, why not just do the syntax highlighting by-hand using style-sheets or something?

Comment: It's more of a convenient in game debugger than anything. But the code is coming together so nicely I've been thinking of features that would be nice to see if I were to distribute this code. Sorry for the late answer I was asleep. Also, I am aware of other debug terminals for XNA, but none implemented in Python. So I thought it would be a good exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studios does not use syntax highlighting. Its IDE performs the language parsing so it can be completely accurate.

You will have to find a third party source in order to use syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed there would be something akin to a .vim file (in the form of a .NET object) for each language VS supports. I maybe have been mistaken.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't use syntax highlighting? Then what do you call the coloring of code keywords, identifiers, operators, comments, literals... etc?

Comment: Language parsing. - [Parser Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator)